# SQLite on delete cascade doesnt work

Tags: sqlite

i have created some tables:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORKOUTPLANS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , NAME TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE, DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE)";
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTITY (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , NAME TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE , DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE)";
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EXERCISE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , NAME TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE , DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE , REPS TEXT NOT NULL , WEIGHT TEXT NOT NULL)";
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WPEN (PLANID, ENID, FOREIGN KEY(PLANID) REFERENCES WORKOUTPLANS(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(ENID) REFERENCES ENTITY(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)";
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENEX (ENTITYID, EXERCISEID, FOREIGN KEY(ENTITYID) REFERENCES ENTITY(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(EXERCISEID) REFERENCES EXERCISE(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)";
```

So as you can see i have to m:n relationships and in this connecting tables i have constraints with on delete cascade. i know that i have to activate foreign keys in sqlite each time i connect to the database and so did i.

however, when i delete a row in WORKOUTPLANS it is just deleting the row in WORKOUTPLANS and in WPEN not in ENTITY, EXERCISE and ENEX

Why is the on delete cascade not working?

Answer (score 1):

It is only deleting from `WORKOUTPLANS` and `WPEN` because the others don't have `on delete cascade` actions for `WORKOUTPLANS`.

Here is a summary of your schema for `on delete cascade` where the left is a table that has a foreign key constraint with `on delete cascade` for the table on the right:

```
WPEN -> WORKOUTPLANS
WPEN -> ENTITY
ENEX -> ENTITY
ENEX -> EXERCISE
```

Therefore, if you delete a row in `WORKOUTPLANS`, it will also delete from `WPEN`. If you delete from `ENTITY` it will also delete from `WPEN` and `ENEX`. If you delete from `EXERCISE`, it will also delete from `ENEX`.

Here is a good [reference link](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) for the `on delete` actions.

Here is a good [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379333/how-to-cascade-delete-over-many-to-many-table) for what it sounds like you want.