# How to delete Many - Many Relationship (Only Joining Table)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core in an ASP.NET Core application. I want to be able to delete the joining linking row in a many to many relationship table (where you only have table1Id & table2Id columns linking the many to many relationship) but the only options I have are

1) SetNull (which I'm assuming tries to set table2Id column ON TABLE2 to null because I can't not perform a update-database and it tells me the reason is because it can't set the foreign key id column to null)

2) Restrict (this is a band-aid fix because it allows me to push but now my users can't delete until they've undone every relationship before deleting)

3) Cascade (this tries to delete EVERYTHING and is definitely not what I want)

there doesn't seem to be just a "DeleteRelationship" option

I have tried to set the id properties in the linking class to nullable (see code)

```
public class PregenProfessionArchetypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel> TrainedParentSkills { get; set; } = new List<PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel>();
    public ICollection<PregenProfessionArchetype_ChildSkill_LinkModel> ChildSkills { get; set; } = new List<PregenProfessionArchetype_ChildSkill_LinkModel>();
    public ICollection<PregenProfessionArchetype_Technique_LinkModel> Techniques { get; set; } = new List<PregenProfessionArchetype_Technique_LinkModel>();
    public ICollection<PregenProfessionArchetype_Talent_LinkModel> Talents { get; set; } = new List<PregenProfessionArchetype_Talent_LinkModel>();
}


public class PregenProfessionArchetype_ChildSkill_LinkModel
{
    public int PregenProfessionArchetypeId { get; set; }
    public PregenProfessionArchetypeModel PregenProfessionArchetype { get; set; }
    public int ChildSkillId { get; set; }
    public ChildSkillModel ChildSkill { get; set; }
}

public class PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel
{
    public int? PregenProfessionArchetypeId { get; set; }
    public PregenProfessionArchetypeModel PregenProfessionArchetype { get; set; }
    public int? ParentSkillId { get; set; }
    public ParentSkillModel ParentSkill { get; set; }
}

public class ChildSkillModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ParentSkillId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Skill")]
    public ParentSkillModel ParentSkill { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; } = 1;


    public ICollection<PregenProfessionArchetype_ChildSkill_LinkModel> PregenProfessionArchetypeLink { get; set; } = new List<PregenProfessionArchetype_ChildSkill_LinkModel>();
}


        // Application Context File Overwritting (Child is same and left out talent)
        builder.Entity<PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel>()
            .HasKey(ttp => new { ttp.ParentSkillId, ttp.PregenProfessionArchetypeId });

        builder.Entity<PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel>()
            .HasOne<PregenProfessionArchetypeModel>(tm => tm.PregenProfessionArchetype)
            .WithMany(tpp => tpp.TrainedParentSkills)
            .HasForeignKey(tm => tm.PregenProfessionArchetypeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel>()
            .HasOne<ParentSkillModel>(tm => tm.ParentSkill)
            .WithMany(tmm => tmm.PregenProfessionArchetypeLink)
            .HasForeignKey(tm => tm.PregenProfessionArchetypeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

The only time I'm able to push is when it is set to restricted. The code shows an example of the classes and their relationship

Error Message: SetNull

```
Failed executing DbCommand (81ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel_ParentSkillModel_PregenProfessionArchetypeId] FOREIGN KEY ([PregenProfessionArchetypeId]) REFERENCES [ParentSkillModel] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Comment: So... How are you trying to delete them? Just removing them from the parent collection? Tried `var toRemove = dbContext.Set<PregenProfessionArchetype_ChildSkill_LinkModel>().FirstOrDefault(x => ....); 
dbContext.Remove(toRemove); dbContext.SaveChanges();` ?

Comment: I'm only trying to delete their link together. Example, if i was to delete a parent skill and it had PregenProfessionalArchetypes associated with it, then it would ONLY delete the links that it had with the Pregens NOT the Pregens themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only delete the links of the join table and the row of parent table when deleting a parent skill , you could use `Cascade` delete which is the default behavior of [required relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#required-relationships)

[Delete behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#delete-behaviors) are defined in the DeleteBehavior enumerator type and can be passed to the OnDelete fluent API to control whether the deletion of a principal/parent entity or the severing of the relationship to dependent/child entities should have a side effect on the dependent/child entities.

In your scenario , `PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel` is the dependent/child entity of `PregenProfessionArchetypeModel` and `ParentSkillModel`. So when deleting Parent its links from `PregenProfessionArchetype_ParentSkill_LinkModel` Table will automatically be deleted because of Cascade, but the Pregens will not be deleted.  And if you want also to delete Pregens that were connected only to that Parent you will have to do it manually.

Reference ：[Entity Framework Core Code-First: Cascade delete on a many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799796/entity-framework-core-code-first-cascade-delete-on-a-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TechniquePrerequisitesLink_TechniqueModel_TechniqueModelId' on table 'TechniquePrerequisitesLink' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: That is an error that I'm getting with one of my models

Comment: Also when I set to cascade then it deletes EVERYTHING including the linked model

Comment: So scratch everything I said... I'm not smart... The cascade is functioning as intended